# How do I keep this trumpet valve in place?

Tags: trumpet, valves

This is the first valve to an older Holton student-model trumpet.

[image]

The little bump (shown with arrow) is supposed to mate with a little notch inside the valve casing, which keeps it rotated properly for playing.  I can't seem to get it to catch, though, and so it rotates around in there and makes the trumpet unplayable.  The other two valves work correctly and I can't figure out what's wrong with this one to make it fail in this manner.

Looking to avoid a costly repair on a not-very-valuable instrument.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you just hold the valve by the valve guide (the little bump), and twist the valve in your hand, does it turn? If yes, the valve guide is probably seating properly in the trumpet, but the guide itself isn't properly attached to the valve itself.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron - the valve glide moves with the valve when I spin it.  I take that to mean that the valve glide is not seating properly in the trumpet.  Compared to the others it does feel worn down.  I'll see if I can find a replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the ‘bump’ is worn down or damaged. Or the slot is dirty or damaged. A repair shop will easily diagnose the problem.

Comment: Yes, this was the solution. The shop charged only $15